# How do I find out how far Falcon Heavy's Starman is from earth right now?

Tags: spacex, falcon-heavy, tesla-roadster

I cannot find out *how far from earth Starman of the Falcon Heavy is right now*, or at any time for that matter. How would I find the distance?

Comment: I do not know if this will help but [the Roadster has been given a couple of designations](https://www.n2yo.com/satellite/?s=43205). NORAD ID: 43205. Int'l Code: **2018-017A**.

Comment: I don't want to ask a separate question because I think OP and I want the same thing. Is there some kind of graphic, showing the orbits of things around the sun, but has a marker on where Spaceman is in relation to those things? I know Elon Musk [tweeted](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DVZ0h3YW4AIc-9w.jpg:large) something like that showing the new trajectory, but I haven't been able to find a "live" version of that. I think that's what OP asks for?

Comment: @coblr That is exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've created a website to tell this information. It isn't perfect, but it is mostly accurate, at least for now. http://www.whereisroadster.com/ As of editing this post,

> The current location is 1,297,260 miles (2,087,737 km, 0.014 AU) from Earth, moving away from Earth at a speed of 6,862 miles/hour (11,043 km/hour, 3.07 km/s).

The information comes from JPL/Horizons, which used SpaceX's ephemeris as well as visual observations to model it's path for some time.

Comment: What is the source of your numbers?

Comment: I'm using a model I created based on the TLEs and the C3 Elon tweeted, and I'm going to update it to use the Ephemeris that SpaceX provided JPL as soon as I can. It should be accurate enough for the moment, but I'm hoping to have increasingly accurate numbers, at least until the fact that we can't track it causes an issue.

Answer (score 4):

https://www.n2yo.com/satellite/?s=43205

DON"T PANIC!

2018-017A

You can track it use this number

Comment: But where does it state the altitude or distance from earth? @matthew-wang

Comment: Perigee: 187.7 km  
Apogee: 6,957.9 km, it shows apa and pea

Comment: But I thought it was supposed to be heading for Mars / past Mars orbit.  Those numbers say it's not going very far at all, as per Steve's "question" below.

Answer (score 2):

Those orbital elements refer to the parking orbit prior to the burn that took it out of earth orbit. The parking orbit was approximately 180 x 6951 km, and it completed two orbits before executing the burn at about 0230 UTC on 7 Feb 2018 just before the second perigee (where it was most energy-efficient to do so). We observed this visually in San Diego during a pass just after local sunset.

NORAD does not maintain elements for objects not in earth orbit but NASA JPL does. You can locate Starman/Tesla/FH through their Horizons online system: horizons.jpl.nasa.gov. It's designed for solar system objects.