# Pi-day challenge; when will Starman/Roadster's orbit reach pi wrt launchpoint or Earth?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, tesla-roadster

In response to today being [pi day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi_Day) (also see http://www.piday.org/), NASA has published it's fifth annual [pi in the sky day 5](https://www.jpl.nasa.gov/edu/teach/activity/pi-in-the-sky-5/) activity set (see also [NASA goes the distance](https://www.jpl.nasa.gov/edu/news/2018/3/9/pi-goes-the-distance-at-nasa/) and [Celebrate Pi Day with NASA](https://www.jpl.nasa.gov/edu/events/2018/3/9/celebrate-pi-day-with-nasa/)).

I've asked about a more challenging pi-based question from NASA [here](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/25478/7982), but this one is more Space SE-based.

1. When will the Starman/Roadster spacecraft have traveled around the Sun by pi radians?
2. When will it reach pi radians with respect to Earth as seen from the Sun (Solar [conjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opposition_(planets)) as seen from Earth)?
3. Will each of these happen before, on, or after next year's pi day?

Comment: Related: [How do I find out how far Falcon Heavy's Starman is from earth right now?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/24936)

Comment: @Tensibai I see no angles given there.

Comment: Yep, sorry, not duplicate, just related. I though there was some math details on the answer site, but my memory is faulty.

Comment: And I worked on, but didn't finish, a modification that will make this easy to do on my website this morning... Sigh. Still...

Comment: Web sites like this are never completely finished, as the possibilities are endless. It's the price to pay for creativity I guess.

Comment: Since HORIZONS tracks this, shouldn't it be possible to find an "exact" answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a few plots from http://www.whereisroadster.com/charts.html

1. I don't have the exact start angle, but it will be about November 11, 2018

[image]

2. It hovers close to, but not quite at, the pi point for almost a year, but I think the final value is Oct 21, 2019.

[image]

3. The first will, the second will not.

Comment: Excellent! The configuration for #2 is close enough to pi "for government work."